# Why is Assigning a value to a field in ADORecordset throwing an error?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

So i'm testing sample code and I pasted some online text into a field and i'm getting an error and I have no clue why.  Here is the entire method which is throwing the error:

> EDIT the error is coming from the assignment.  However, there is no
>   error thrown on any number of other input strings.

```
   CurNodeName = RTrim(CurNodeName)

   ADORecordset.Fields.Append CurNodeName, adVarChar, 500, adFldMayBeNull

    tempString = XMLValueDecode(CurNodeValue)
    ADORecordset.Fields(CurNodeName).Value = tempString
```

...

Here is the string which is being passed into the method:

> Most of the methods of the DoCmd object have arguments ? some are
>   required, while others are optional. If you omit optional arguments,
>   the arguments assume the default values for the particular method. For
>   example, the OpenForm method uses seven arguments, but only the first
>   argument, FormName, is required. The following example shows how you
>   can open the Employees form in the current database. Only employees
>   with the title Sales Representative are included.

Here is the exact error description:

> Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.

That is the whole story, and i just don't understand it.  Can you tell me why this error is happening?

Comment: Multi-step operation usually points to loading a value into a variable that can't take it.  But I see no issue with what you are doing.  It works for me.  Maybe problem is specific to the 2003 version of Access.

Comment: Try doing all the replaces on the text variable. Then at the end set XMLValueDecode = Text

Comment: Does `Call Prompt()` compile in Access 2003 VBA?  Access 2010 complains *"Sub or Function not defined"*

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: There is plenty to do reducing and simplifying this function in order to isolate the error.  Also, setting `.Value` from a function while also trying to apply `RTrim()` is definitely out of order.

Comment: I added the calling code and edited the Trim out of the assignment line.  I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I've seen this error when the value you are trying to save into a field is longer than the size the field can contain, or if there is a data type mismatch, but likely it is length.

Comment: To test that, use `Debug.Print XMLValueDecode(CurNodeValue)` instead of assigning to the field.  Then check the result in the Immediate Window.

Comment: input string has a length of 462.  The field is declared with a size of 500.  How about adVarChar?  I'll google that now.

Comment: with an empty , , it was an error.  With 500 back in it (and 1000) and the adLongVarChar it threw the same error.

Comment: Sorry, that was a wild guess and it was wrong.  But I've now tested your original `ADORecordset.Fields.Append`, and mine later accepts a 462 character string without complaint.  We may need to see more context showing how you create and use that recordset.

Comment: my only guess is the ? is a problem.  I changed the type to a adVarWChar  based on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536358/are-there-restricted-characters-in-ado-varchars  I don't know why that worked, but it seems to have.  If you know why please post and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(From a comment to another answer:)*

> There must be some critical difference between adVarChar type and adVarWChar that the text being set responded differently to.

It was many versions ago (Access 2000, and the release of Jet 4.0) that `Text` and `Memo` fields in Access were upgraded to handle Unicode. From that point forward, `Text` fields and parameters needed to be referenced as `adVarWChar` (with a maximum length of 255), while `Memo` fields and parameters needed to be referenced as `adVarWChar` or `adLongVarWChar` (with a theoretical size limit of approximately 1 billion characters).

It is unclear why the code in the question would work for some strings and not others, but certainly using the correct ("W") data type would be a prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `curNodeName` for type? If you've passed a numerical type to append, it might be converting it to string implicitly when naming the field to avoid indexing errors, if that's the case, (and you are inadvertently trying to assign that string to the value of a field with an index that is not currently in the collection,) you might be throwing that multi error because you'd be trying to assign a string of a length longer than the default length to a field with an index way outside the current collection (either of which error alone might throw a specific exception, but depending on the way the parser is handling those terms, it might evaluate each side of the assignment for validity before trying to assign an error code.)

What I'm wondering is if you've debug.printed (or just counted, depending on collection size) the field names and indices as matched pairs and tried assigning the string to your field by index instead of name?

Comment: If that first thing is happening, you should be able to assign it by using `CStr(curNodeName)` in both the append and assignment line.

Comment: It strikes me that it shouldn't really be possible because one of the rules of XML is that no tag can start with a number. Still, if it's typed as variant or something, an explicit conversion might work out for you.

Comment: CurNodeName value is SubText.  There must be some critical difference between adVarChar type and adVarWChar  that the text being set responded differently to.